# Repairing Crack in Drywall

Tags: drywall, walls, crack, patching-drywall

I have a crack abutting and running the length of a door frame; a French door that opens outside. I have repaired drywall damage, so I tried to work from that angle; using spackling to patch it. The spackling didn't take and I'm left to wonder what I should actually do to repair this. I have attached a picture.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the door frame is not securely fastened, and moves when the door is forcefully opened or closed? This would need to be remedied before patching.

Comment: Thanks! I had not actually considered that; rather I had thought this was a factor of the house settling. Beyond opening and closing the door and watching for movement, how else could I test this? If this is the source could you refer me to an article on fastening this in place properly? I know we do have to close the door hard to get it to close fully.

Answer (score 2):

Scrap all the junk off the seam and wall, then sand it. Get some fiberglass mesh drywall tape and some joint compound and seam it. If you're not familiar with taping drywall, there are countless videos on the subject on the internet. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that tonight.

Answer (score 0):

If the gap is wider at the top then you have a door to wall connection issue with is common with french doors which are typically larger and heavier than normal doors.

Before patching, replace one of the screws in the top hinge with a 3" long screw of the same size (usually #8 or #10) and screw it into the stud. Don't over-tighten or it mmight pull the hinge towards the stud causing other problems.

Then scrape off the old and patch with mud and tape.